# how to put controller in external html file angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I am quite new in AngularJS.

I have a web app that has some buttons:

index.html

```
<button class="aButton">a</button>  
<button class="bButton">b</button>

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".aButton").click(function(){
        $(".aField").fadeIn(400);
      });
   });
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".bButton").click(function(){
        $(".bField").fadeIn(400);
      });
   });
</script>
```

and when I click on the different buttons, they show iframes depending on the clicked button. In these iframes I put an external html file by src.

```
<iframe class="aField" style="display: none;" src="a.html" width="700" height="1000" ></iframe>
<iframe class="bField" style="display: none;" src="b.html" width="700" height="1000" ></iframe>
```

Until here no problem.

The problem is in the external html files (a.html and b.html) that need a different controller each.
I tried to put the ng-controller tag in the iframe and in the external html files but the functions that I have defined in the controller do not work.

Any idea?
If I was not clear, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are loading iframes then the content won't know anything about angular so controllers won't function in the external HTML.

You might want to look at [`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) for including partial HTML files into your page. Using this, the HTML will be inserted directly into your page and compiled/linked like the rest of the app.

Below is an example using `ng-include`. I have also replaced the jQuery click handlers with [`ng-click`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick) and the `.fadeIn`s with `ng-show` to make the solution a bit more angular.

```
<!-- These buttons just set variables on the scope when clicked -->
<button ng-click="showA=true">a</button>  
<button ng-click="showB=true">b</button>

<script>
  // Nothing left here now
  // The contents of ng-click could be moved into a JS controller here...
</script>

<!-- the ng-include attribute value is an angular expression. If you use a string, wrap it in quotes -->
<div ng-include="'a.html'" ng-show="showA" width="700" height="1000"></div>
<div ng-include="'b.html'" ng-show="showB" width="700" height="1000" ></div>
```

Comment: Agree ng-include is the way to go.  When you have an iframe it has it's own context and doesn't seem to inherit anything from the wrapping page (CSS etc., I fought with this on the facebook plugins, some things could be done with classes but nothing can be applied based on the iframe context from what I could tell... possibly a javascript workaround, but wasn't worth it).

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I tried your solution in these ways:

    <iframe class="aField" style="display: none;" ng-include src="a.html" ng-controller="controllerA" width="700" height="1000" ></iframe>

and like this:
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controllerA">
<iframe class="aField" style="display: none;" ng-include="a.html" width="700" height="1000" ></iframe> 

but it does not works...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to use `iframe` if you have `ng-include`. It works either like a replacement for the `iframe` element, or like a `src` attribute that you can put on other elements (usually div), but I'm not sure it will work on `iframe`. I'll add an example to my answer shortly.